# Word for two collections that do not have any elements in common

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word for when you have a collection A and a collection B and they have no overlap.

In mathematical terms: the relation between two sets where the intersection is empty. Like in this Venn diagram:

[image: Empty intersection]

The word that keeps popping up in my mind is *disparate sets*, but I don't feel that completely covers the meaning when I look at the definition, because that doesn't seem to preclude overlapping sets that are different:

> **disparate**
>   1. distinct in kind; essentially different; dissimilar:
>   *disparate ideas*.

Comment: *Disparate* is usually applied to a group of items which contain elements which have little in common. The United Nations has a *disparate* membership.

Comment: I might describe them as *distinct* sets, but as that already appears in your question, you may have already considered that

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want ***disjoint***, as in "*disjoint sets*".

From [Wolfram Mathworld:](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjointSets.html)

> ***Disjoint Sets***
>
> *Two sets A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> are disjoint if their intersection A<sub>1</sub> ∩ A<sub>2</sub> = ∅, where ∅ is the empty set.*
>
> *Disjoint sets are also said to be **mutually exclusive** or **independent.***

Comment: This answer includes the words I would use most often. I also hear the word ***unrelated*** used for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider *[orthogonal](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=orthogonal)*

> Very different or unrelated; sharply divergent: "Radical Islamists are ultimately seeking to create something orthogonal to our model of democracy" (Richard A. Clarke). [*American Heritage*]

This suggest something *very different*, not just non-overlapping.

Comment: I would use _orthogonal_ when the criteria for one set are disjoint with the criteria for the other; in a sense, when the two sets cannot be meaningfully compared. Not apples _vs._ oranges but apples _vs._ a list of dictionary words.

Comment: It may be worht pointing out that many mathematicians use "orthogonal" as a synonym for "unrelated", often in a tounge-in-cheek manner. (I can't say for the rest of the population). This being said, I would imagine two "orthogonal" things to have as much in common as two random things. Orthogonal lines meet in one point, not zero.

Comment: (Following from @Feanor's point) Orthogonal means "right-angled". While for some things this might imply "very different", for others it will imply "completely independent". Most people with a STEM background will assume the latter. In the following examples "x" indicates orthogonality: tall-short x thin-fat x lawful-unlawful x good-evil x capitalist-communist x liberal-conservative. Despite every attribute being orthogonal, short, overweight, lawful-"morally questionable", conservative communists [do exist](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02088/korea_kim-jong-il-_2088541b.jpg).