# Is there a common or well understood word for 'a group with no shared members'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have two mathematical sets that have no common elements.

[image]

In mathematical terms, these are called 'disjoint sets', and together they are called a 'partition'.

What common or well understood word or phrase could I use to explain what these are, when speaking to someone who doesn't know what a disjoint set or partition is?

**Edit**: I am looking for an alternative to the answer found in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206850/word-for-two-collections-that-do-not-have-any-elements-in-common). I am looking for a reasonably common word/phrase to *replace* "disjoint". The other answer found in the linked question, "orthogonal", is *much* too obscure for my purpose.

Comment: A heterogeneous set of numbers?

Comment: No, a single set can't be disjoint, so there's no such thing as a disjoint set (singular). Instead, any N sets (N > 1) can be disjoint sets (plural) if none of them have any members in common. If you don't want to use _disjoint_, you'll have to say "with no members in common" or the like; this is not a distinction English makes lexically.

Comment: Perhaps, but I was hoping there would be a shorter phrase, or possibly a single word, that explains this concept. @Josh61

Comment: *mutually exclusive*

Comment: "Two separated sets" ? Quite understandable, this expression also refers to a mathematical definition: *In topology and related branches of mathematics, separated sets are pairs of subsets of a given topological space that are related to each other in a certain way: roughly speaking, neither overlapping nor touching. The notion of when two sets are separated or not is important both to the notion of connected spaces (and their connected components) as well as to the separation axioms for topological spaces.*

Comment: Zach, the answers to the other question do not answer your question. The best answer there, _disjoint_, is what you ask an alternative for, and I wonder how many people would understand the other, orthogonal. So it's unfortunate this was marked duplicate, as it will discourage additional answers. When you want to ask somenthing very close to an existing question it is safe practice to refer to the other question and explain why yours is different. You might still be able to edit your question to that effect and flag it to atract the moderator's attention and have its duplcate status lifted.

Comment: I've taken your advice and [edited](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/276082/revisions) to explain why this is not a duplicate. Thanks. @Jacinto

Comment: First a disclaimer that the accepted answer to the other question is my own, but did you notice that in addition to *disjoint* it offered the more mundane alternatives *mutually exclusive* and  *independent*? Note also the *question* contains some alternatives: *distinct*, *disparate*.

Comment: I did take those words and phrases into consideration, but I still feel they aren't *quite* what I'm looking for. @DanBron

Comment: Hmm. In that case your best best is to do some contemplation and try to identify precisely as possible what you *are* looking for, and then describe it in your question, along with the other terms you've considered and why they don't fit the bill. If you don't know quite what you're looking for, it's no use asking us ;)

Comment: If this question is to be reopened changing the title might be a good idea too. Something like _what else other than "disjoint" can we call_... As it is now it really looks like a duplicate.

Comment: @DanBron The way I see it is if a question has an answer accepted already, and the answer is massively upvoted, and it is the right answer, then it is unlikely anybody will make any additional suggestion (nobody has for 10 months). And even if I thought  _mutually exclusive_ a good option, which I think it is, I would still like to see whether people might come up with other ideas, which they may well do if the question is reopened as it is now.

Comment: @Jacinto Can't argue with you except to say: that's the StackExchange model. Many people see it as a flaw (in many cases, myself included), but so far no one has come up with an idea which addresses it without introducing new, worse, drawbacks.

Comment: You should change the title, emphasize you want a layman term to describe a mathematical "problem". As it currently stands the two questions are the same. May I suggest using a thesaurus for the other expressions suggested in Dan Bron's answer, you might get that flashbulb moment!

Comment: How about "unshared"?

Comment: Seems to me like you've got your elements "divided into two groups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-overlapping, all-encompassing sets.

Answer (score 0):

"Two **separate** groups"

I would take the word "separate" to mean there are no common members, unless stated otherwise.