# Is there a word for 'groups' that implies mutual exclusivity?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I have a series of items that I need to categorize. However, I would like to convey in a word that each item should really only belong to one specific category or group. Because of this intended mutual exclusivity, using the word "category" or the word "group" seems insufficient.

For example, imagine I had these items:

```
Blue
Orange
Soda
Basketball
Green
Football
Coffee
```

Possible values for acceptable 'group' names would be:

```
Color
Beverage
Sports
```

If I were to say, "To which group does 'Basketball' belong?", it's possible someone would respond by using both Sports and Color, since a basketball is orange. Words such as "bucket" or "bin" have been suggested as the implicit physical limitations of those items would help someone infer that an item can only belong to one. These seem like a good alternative.

Are there any words that are more explicit about the one-to-one nature of the grouping?

Comment: Welcome, but I'm sorry to inform you naming things is specifically off topic here. Please take the [tour].

Comment: @mattbryanswan ... I take it you're asking for a word that means "disjoint set with a meaningful connection among its members". If that's the case, you might want to rephrase the question to fit.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing named data structure like 'Set', 'Multiset', 'List', 'Bag', Dicitonary'? It doesn't exist as a data structure label, but the generic term 'category' implies separation into mutually exclusive sets. Also, 'Group' has a technical meaning which I'm pretty sure you don't mean. 'Category' does also but that's another situation entirely.

Comment: @PhilSweet Hi Phil! I believe my question is valid and appropriate, but my wording within my specific use case was not. I've edited the question to speak more generally. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think ‘Category’ does not imply exclusivity unless stated, @Mitch.

Comment: @Jelila 'Categorize' implies putting an element into a collection, implying that you're only putting the element into one category at a time, implying that the different collections do not share any elements implying they are mutually exclusive. The implication is not hard and fast, but it would be counter-intuitive to allow that an element could belong to more than one category. Most of the [definitions of 'category'](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+category) involve connotative terms like 'division' or 'distinct' implying mutual exclusivity

Comment: @Mitch well, when organising data, if we 'categorise it' it doesn't necessarily mean into only one category. It is common to have say a list with 3 categories for example and put a 1 in each column to signify whether an item belongs in that category or not, having each item able to appear in multiple columns depending on what the data organisation needs are. Data and the world is complex, and categories can reflect that. My jewellery can often be in multiple categories like pendant, silver, figure. If I had to choose an exclusive category it would be 'jewellery' - might hamper my organisation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main feature of the 'groups' that you want to highlight is that each is a [disjoint set](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206850/word-for-two-collections-that-do-not-have-any-elements-in-common) (an item can't be in more than one group at a time), then I'd consider using an analogous real world object's name. At the most generic level, your group is a ***container***, but you might also consider, box, bin or bucket.

***Bucket*** is a good choice, because nobody imagines an object being inside more than one bucket at a time, or (full) buckets within buckets, whereas containers in general can be nested. The word in already used in software design patterns like the [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) precisely because of those connotations.

You could highlight that each 'group' is a particular category of thing by calling them *named buckets*.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive Category. Or mutually Exclusive.

You can say ‘to which single group should each of these items belong?’ This clearly means ‘each item can only go in one category.’

But you might need to explain why ‘sport’ should be chosen over ‘colour’ for basketball by saying something like ‘pick the single best group to which each item can belong’.  Best then is a ‘selection criterion’.

‘Single group’ makes it very clear that they can only belong to one category.

You can use ‘single category’ in the same way.

Bucket or bag - you still need the word ‘single’ to tell people to put each item in only one bag, so I don’t think that helps at all.

Examples:

- select a single category for each item
- place each item in only one bag
- choose the best single category for each item

The generic term for such an assignation is still ‘single group’ or ‘single category ‘.

Another expression you can use is ‘exclusive category’ which means ‘things belonging to it cannot also belong in any other category’.

- Place each item in one exclusive category
- Each item belongs in an exclusive category

‘Mutually exclusive’ means that if they belong to one category, they cannot belong to another.

- place each item in one, mutually exclusive category

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity